# Match text to attribute value w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have the following vars

```
var $headers = $("#myTbl th").not(":first");

var $this = $(this);
```

How do I match **$this.text();**
to the text within *title* tag inside *th*?

```
<th title="match this title">value</th>
```

This does not seem to work:

```
$headers.filter(":contains(" + $this.text() + ")");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var title = $("#myTbl th").not(":first").attr("title");
var $headers = $("#myTbl th[title='"+title+"']");
```

something like that should do it